# Edit row in gridview in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

In one GridView in c# it's possible for authorized user editing the single row on MySql table.

The parameters to editing are: `theNumber` (int), `theAnnotation` (char) and `theUpload` (FileUpload char).

My problem is when the row to editing already contain in field of table `theUpload` one value, e.g.:

```
http://.../public/08072015.pdf
```

This value it is the location from which you can download the file, previously added on this row.

If in this row try edit the values of fields `theNumber` and `theAnnotation` and not edit the field `theUpload` because the value is existing, the update query deleted the value existing in field `theUpload`.

How to edit the row of GridView without that memorized information are deleted?

I don't think that every change on the row you need to reload the same file.

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

My code below:

```
private void UpdateRow(
    string theNumber,
    string theAnnotation,
    string thefilename,
    string theID)
{
    string sql = String.Format(@"Update `UserTable` SET 
                                         theNumber = {0},                                              
                                         theAnnotation  = '{1}',
                                         thefilename = '{2}',
                                         WHERE ID = {3}; ",
                                    theNumber.ToString(),
                                    theAnnotation.ToString(),
                                    thefilename.ToString(),
                                    theID.ToString());
    using (OdbcConnection cn =
      new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = 
          new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            gv.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }
    }
}



protected void gv_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string theID = gv.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    TextBox theNumber = (TextBox)row.FindControl("theNumber");
    TextBox theAnnotation = (TextBox)row.FindControl("theAnnotation");
    FileUpload thefilename = (FileUpload)row.FindControl("thefilename");

    theNumber1 = theNumber.Text;
    theAnnotation1 = theAnnotation.Text.ToString().Replace("'", "`");

    filename = Path.GetFileName(thefilename.PostedFile.FileName).ToString();
    FileExtention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(thefilename.FileName);
    int fileSize = thefilename.PostedFile.ContentLength;

    if (fileSize > 0)
    {
        if (filename.ToString() != "")
        {
            if (FileExtention == ".pdf")
            {
                thefilename.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("public/" + filename.ToString()));
                filename = "http://.../public/" + filename.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
               ...
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        filename = "";
    }

    UpdateRow(theNumber1.ToString(), theAnnotation1.ToString(), filename.ToString(), ID.ToString());
}
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @Mainak: thank you for reply, I have added my `code behind` in first question.

Comment: what happens when you fire the row editing command ? I mean what happens to your gridview row ?

Comment: @Mainak: If try edit the values of fields `theNumber` and `theAnnotation` and not edit the field `theUpload` because the value is existing, the update query deleted the value existing in field `theUpload`.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your query or your code . So I would suggest before you update a particular row try to read the values particularly the value that gets deleted(theUpload) and in your query include the value of the cloumn(theUpload) when you update your row .